# In Python, how to find all the files under a directory, including the files in subdirectories?

Tags: python, list, file

Is there any built in functions to find all the files under a particular directory including files under subdirectories ?
I have tried this code, but not working...may be the logic itself is wrong...

```
def fun(mydir):
    lis=glob.glob(mydir)
    length=len(lis)
    l,i=0,0
    if len(lis):
        while(l+i<length):
            if os.path.isfile(lis[i]):
                final.append(lis[i])
                lis.pop(i)
                l=l+1
                i=i+1
            else:
                i=i+1
            print final
        fun(lis)
    else:
        print final
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no built-in function, but using [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) it's trivial to construct it:

```
import os
def recursive_file_gen(mydir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
        for file in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, file)
```

**ETA**: the `os.walk` function walks directory tree recursively; the `recursive_file_gen` function is a generator (uses `yield` keyword to produce next file). To get the resulting list do:

```
list(recursive_file_gen(mydir))
```

Comment: @pythbegin: added explanation, do ask if any specific point is not clear.

Comment: @pyth: there is a [formal definition in Python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement).

Comment: ok...
I made some changes to your code and it is like this now
def listall(parent):
 lis=[]
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent):
  for name in files:
   if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root,name))>500000:
    lis.append(os.path.join(root,name))
 return lis


My aim is to find all the files with size greater than 500000...and it is working properly...
But when I used this function on 'Temporary Internet Files' folder in Windows am getting this error...
I think its because of the special characters in the file name.
Can u suggest something ?

Comment: sorry...I forgot to mention the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    listall(a)
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 5, in listall
    if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root,name))>500000:
  File "C:\Python26\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\khedarnatha\\Local Settings\\Temporary Internet Files\\Content.IE5\\EDS8C2V7\\??????+1[1].jpg'
This is it

Comment: @pyth: I suspect it has to do with the encoding of the file name. It's hard to say, since you don't provide sample of the file names. Clearly, `?` cannot be present in the filename, since it's invalid. Try to see what was the actual name of the file. What did `os.walk` returned and what `os.path.join` returned. I'd suggest you ask separate question, as it is beyond limits of this one.

Comment: It't not recommended to use _file_ as a variable name, as it shadows built-in name _file_. However, in this case, it doesn't make any difference. Used your snipped! Thank you. +1

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend this path module, written by Jason Orendorff:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py/2.2

Unfortunately, his website is down now, but you can still download from the above link (or through `easy_install`, if you prefer).

Using this path module, you can do various actions on paths, including the walking files you requested.  Here's an example:

```
from path import path

my_path = path('.')

for file in my_path.walkfiles():
    print file

for file in my_path.walkfiles('*.pdf'):
    print file
```

There are also convenience functions for many other things to do with paths:

```
In [1]: from path import path

In [2]: my_dir = path('my_dir')

In [3]: my_file = path('readme.txt')

In [5]: print my_dir / my_file
my_dir/readme.txt

In [6]: joined_path = my_dir / my_file

In [7]: print joined_path
my_dir/readme.txt

In [8]: print joined_path.parent
my_dir

In [9]: print joined_path.name
readme.txt

In [10]: print joined_path.namebase
readme

In [11]: print joined_path.ext
.txt

In [12]: joined_path.copy('some_output_path.txt')

In [13]: print path('some_output_path.txt').isfile()
True

In [14]: print path('some_output_path.txt').isdir()
False
```

There are more operations that can be done too, but these are some of the ones that I use most often.  Notice that the `path` class inherits from `string`, so it can be used wherever a `string` is used.  Also, notice that two or more `path` objects can easily be joined together by using the overridden `/` operator.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

os.walk() is what you need.

But for added performance, try the package [scandir](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir). It also part of the standard library in Python 3.5 and is described in [PEP 471](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)