# Iterating through individual files in os.walk in Python in an idiomatic fashion

Tags: python, list, generator, list-comprehension, os.walk

I started with some code I got from [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865278/in-python-how-to-find-all-the-files-under-a-directory-including-the-files-in-s/2865328#2865328) to generate full paths for all the files in a directory tree:

```
import os
def recursive_file_gen(mydir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
        for file in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, file)
```

I wanted to add memoization, and it seemed to me the easiest way to achieve was just to make recursive_file_gen return a list instead:

```
def recursive_file_list(mydir):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
        for file in files:
            result.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return result
```

This code is fine, really. It's certainly not hard to figure out what's going on. But putting together a list using successive `append` operations isn't fully Pythonic. My guess is there's a better way using Python syntax, probably via a list comprehension, and learning it would be edifying.

Of course I could write:

```
def recursive_file_list(mydir):
    return list(recursive_file_gen(mydir))
```

and memoize that. But I'm wondering if there's anything cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about?

```
result = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, dir, files in os.walk(mydir) for file in files]
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I think I may have been trying `[os.path.join(root, file) for file in files for root, dir, files in os.walk(mydir)]` at some point (the two `for` clauses in the opposite order) which doesn't work. Getting the order wrong turns out to be dangerous: after I've run your answer (so there's something bound to `files`), the version with the order wrong actually runs, but gives garbage output.